# ¿Registros no asociados a un usuario?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

necesito obtener todos los **Servicios** que no estén asociados a las **solicitudes** las cual están asociadas a un **usuario**.

Entonces básicamente los modelos son

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */


   protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'roles'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token','profesion_id'
    ];
     public function solicitudes(){
      return $this->hasMany(SolicitudServicio::class);
    }

}
```

El modelo de solicitud de servicio

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SolicitudServicio extends Model
{
  protected $table ="solicitudes";
  protected $fillable = ['url', 'servicio', 'servicio_id', 'nequipos', 'nequipos_asignados','username','password', 'ndias'];
//Metodo del operador
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
  }

  public function servicio(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Servicio::class);
  }
  public function estado(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Estado::class); //es estado de solicitud
  }

  public function tipo(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Tipo::class); //Es tipo de solicitud
  }
  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }  
}
```

El modelo de de servicio

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Servicio extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'servicios';
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'description'];

  public function solicitudesDeServicio(){
    return $this->hasMany(SolicitudServicio::class);
  }
  public function funciones(){
    return $this->hasMany(FuncioneServicio::class);
  }
}
```

Entonces como les comentaba necesito los servicios que no estan asociados a los servicios los cuales están asociados a un usuario.

Antualmente tengo este query utilizando *Relationships* el cual solo me devuelve los servicios que si estan asociados a los servicio de un usuario que en este caso es el usuario con id 1.

Entonces lo que necesito es lo contrario, he revisado la **documentacion** de laravel y existe una función interesante *whereNotIn* pero no he logrado hacerla funcionar en el *query*

```
$solicitudes = App\Servicio::whereHas('solicitudesDeServicio',function($query) {

    $query->whereHas('user',function($query2) {

        $query2->where('id','1');

    });

})->get();
```

Comment: Podrías hacer un left join, pero es difícil darte una respuesta clara, tus modelos aún que pueden ser funcionales son incompletos, y no quedan totalmente claras las PK y las FK y por lo tanto no quedan claras las relaciones, mi recomendacion es definir las siempre aún que puedan ser opcionales.

Comment: @Xerif puedes ver que el OP respondió su propia pregunta antes que tú pusieras este comentario, en todo caso no entiendo por qué dices que están incompletos los modelos?

Answer (score 0):

Prefecto ya encontré la solución en otra parte de la documentación de laravel utilizando la función `whereDoesntHave`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Entonces básicamente mi query quedo de la siguiente manera

```
$solicitudes = App\Servicio::whereDoesntHave('solicitudesDeServicio',function($query){
    $query->whereHas('user',function($query2){
         $query2->where('id','1');});
})->get();
```